# Can't inject a property from a test properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

To my surprise, I discovered that for some reason I can't inject a property from a test properties file. Here's an MRE:

#### Test

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

import static com.example.dynamicgateway.misc.ConfigPropertiesTest.ConfigPropertiesTestConfig;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ConfigPropertiesTestConfig.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class ConfigPropertiesTest {
    @Value("${myapp.server}")
    String server;
    @Test
    void test() {
        System.out.println(); // just to stop the debugger, but it never gets here, fails on startup
    }

    @Configuration
    static class ConfigPropertiesTestConfig {
        @Bean
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
            return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer(); // I even included this post processor
        }
    }
}
```

#### Properties

```
server.port=8080

myapp.server=http://localhost:${server.port}
```

#### Exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'myapp.server' in value "${myapp.server}"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Boot 3.2.1.

Answer (score 4):

When you run all those tests with a mere `SpringExtension`, all the sweet features of Spring Boot are out of the window. You were right to manually include that `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` (`PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`), but you forgot to specify `@PropertySources` – one of those things Boot does for you. Here, it fixes it:

```java
    @Configuration
    @PropertySource("classpath:application-test.properties")
    static class ConfigPropertiesTestConfig {
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe two of the simplest things to do are either

### 1. Using `@SpringBootTest` with direct properties

Use `@SpringBootTest` instead of `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` and setting the properties on the annotation directly, aka something like

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = { ConfigPropertiesTestConfig.class }, 
properties = {
    "server.port=8080",
    "myapp.server=http://localhost:${server.port}"
})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class ConfigPropertiesTest {
  // ...
}
```

### 2. Changing the context configuration to enable more of Spring's auto-setup

IE, changing

```
    @Configuration
    static class ConfigPropertiesTestConfig {
        @Bean
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
            return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer(); // I even included this post processor
        }
    }
```

to

```
    @SpringBootConfiguration
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    static class ConfigPropertiesTestConfig {
    }
```

Generally speaking, the context you specify for the test really will need to turn on all the parts you want/need; For example if you also wanted component-scanning for the test, you'd explicilty set that too (or perhaps just `@Import` a few other configurations directly).

Its also worth mentioning that if the desire is to not turn on auto-configure for everything, you can either `@Import` the auto-config classes you desire and/or exclude certain auto configurations if that's easier. Although both cases will require a little digging to find the actual relevant java classes.